# What is the error and why is it triggered -"Got error 28 from storage engine" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to run a query in MYSQL and the DB engine without executing, returned me an error message as "Got error 28 from storage engine".
What is its significance and y was it triggered...

Answer (score 5):

```
# perror 28
OS error code  28:  No space left on device
```

i.e. you've run out of disk space either in the main mysql data directory, or in the mysql tmp directory.